# stucked in next js 13 app directory dark/light mode function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

i want to export a variable from one component to layout.tsx but it is exported as function which ultimately cause conditional check in class name as permanently true

here's the code :

// file from where i want to export variable 'mode'

```
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CiBrightnessUp, CiCloudMoon } from "react-icons/ci";
export let mode: boolean;

const ToggleThemeIcon = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(false);
  mode = theme;
  console.log(mode);
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className="w-10 h-10 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg dark:bg-slate-800 hover:ring:2 ring-blue-400 pl-3 mt-1"
        onClick={() => setTheme(!theme)}
        aria-label="toggle dark mode"
      >
        {theme ? <CiBrightnessUp /> : <CiCloudMoon />}
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ToggleThemeIcon;
```

// file from where i want to import variable 'mode'

```
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import "./globals.css";
import mode from "./ToggleTheme";
// import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

// export const metadata = {
//   title: 'Create Next App',
//   description: 'Generated by create next app',
// }

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    // <ThemeProvider enableSystem={true} attribute="class">
    <html lang="en" className={mode ? "dark" : ""}>
      <body>
        {" "}
        <div className=" dark:bg-slate-900  dark:text-white bg-gray-400 ">
          <Header />
          {children} <Footer />
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    // </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

want its solution of the problem

Comment: You should not export a variable as it leads to unexpected behaviour. Use React Context API instead

Answer (score -1):

take this example
// layout.tsx

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "@/components/themeProvider";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
          <Nav />
          {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

// themeProvider.tsx

```
    "use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from "next-themes";
import { ThemeProviderProps } from "next-themes/dist/types";

export function ThemeProvider({ children, ...props }: ThemeProviderProps) {
  return <NextThemesProvider {...props}>{children}</NextThemesProvider>;
}
```